# Boid Collation causing Teleportation

Tags: animation, particles, collision

When using the boid particle system, the boids teleport when they fly near a collision object. Even if they don't collide, they teleport to be in contact with the collision object on the Z axis.

https://youtu.be/BPhHn4z5rHE

I tried splitting the collision object into separate pieces, but it didn't fix the issue. The boids need at least a separate, goal and avoid collision.